# Animating a Floating Action Button Activity Transition

Tags: android, material-design, android-transitions

The Material Design Guidelines suggest that you transition a floating action button into a new Activity, after you click on the button.

[Example Video from Guidelines](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B8v7jImPsDi-RWVHZjYybnlDeUE/components-buttons-fab-transition_fullscreen_02.webm)

I tried to animate this with Activity transition, as intoduced in API 21 (Lollipop) but I can't find a way to transform from the color of the button to the color of the toolbar. (I used [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) Floating Action Button)

Obviously, the example isn't an actual demo running on android, but the device that is displayed is clearly a smartphone. Therefore there has to be a way to code this kind of transition, or else Google would not have added this on their Guidelines, would they?

Can I use Activities to achieve this or do I have to use Fragments?

Answer (score -2):

As `FloatingActionButton` descends from `ImageButton` and adds only a few new methods,you can use `setBackgroundColor()` of `ImageButton` to change its background.

Comment: The question is not about the FAB's animation itself but about the transition of activity/fragment AFTER it was clicked.